# Linq, how to search French accents

Tags: database, linq, entity-framework

I have SQL Query like

```
select * from user where firstname like '%Je%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

Is Linq able to do things like this?

I can use ExecuteStoreQuery, but like to know if Linq can to this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

French accents should be no problem

```
var results = from u in _context.User
          where u.firstname.Contains("é")
          select u
```

Comment: When user search for it, they sometimes enter "e", but they want to find "é".

Comment: @DanielZ you could replace the chars in user input's string.

Comment: When user search for "oe", they need find "Joe" and "Joé"

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a SQL view that applies the collation?

For example,

```
CREATE VIEW UserSearch AS
    SELECT *
        , FirstName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI AS FirstNameSearch 
    FROM User
```

Then you can do

```
var results = from us in _context.UserSearch
              where us.FirstNameSearch.Contains("é")
              join u in _context.User on us.UserId equals u.UserId
              select u
```

Comment: This is not Linq way. Compare to use view, use ExecuteStoreQuery is easier.

Comment: View only has to be done once, and then you can use it in LINQ.  ExecuteStoreQuery can't do composition.  What if you just want one or two columns?  Now you have to grab all the columns out of the database, whereas the VIEW/LINQ will translate the query appropriately.  Similarly you can't join on ExecuteStoreQuery and if you apply a where clause afterwards, it will still bring in the whole result set instead of applying it on the database.

Comment: Anyway, why not just set the collation this way in the table if this is how you want the data collated?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just like to know is Linq able to do it, I have no problem doing it by using view, store procedure or query.